# How can I ensure only 1 instance of an operator (used in multiple dags) runs in Airflow, at any given time?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am using an operator (subdag operator, with `taskid "XYZ"`) in `DAG A`, and I also have another subdag operator with same `taskid` (i.e `"XYZ"`) in `DAG B`. Given this scenario, how can I ensure that no more than 1 instance of `"XYZ"` is running at any give time. `DAG A` and `DAG B` can run in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to create a pool with 1 worker slot, and assign this pool to the task ids that cannot be run simultaneously. In this case I had only one task id (operator) `XYZ` where in I had to ensure that it's task instances don't run simultaneously.

Not sure if this is the idiomatic way, but worked for me!